# Attempt to begin reordering on collection view while reordering is already in progress

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have implement drag and drop between two UICollectionViews. Sometimes I get this weird error.

```
Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.54.4/UICollectionView.m:8459

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to begin reordering on collection view while reordering is already in progress'
```

My setup is as follows,

1. I have two UICollectionViews(e.g. A & B)
2. Re-ordering is enabled in both collection views
3. When you drag an item from A to B. The operation is copy
4. When you drag an item from B to A. The operation is delete from B. A is not effected.

My code so far is as follows(abstract version)

```
// Drop delegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    print(#function)
    let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
    if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
        destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        self.performDrop(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
    } else if collectionView.tag == CollectionView.timeline.rawValue {
        // Get last index path of collection view.
        let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
        let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
        destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        self.performDrop(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
    print(#function)
    if session.localDragSession != nil {
        // Trying to drag and drop an item within the app
        if collectionView.hasActiveDrag {
            // Trying to re-oder within the same collection view
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        } else {
            // Trying to copy an item from another collection view
            return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
    } else {
        // Trying to drag and drop an item from a different app
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
    }
}

// Drag delegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    print(#function)
    var item: Item?
    if collectionView.tag == CollectionView.media.rawValue {
        item = mediaItems[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        item = StoryManager.sharedInstance.timelineItems[indexPath.row]
    }

    if let item = item {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item.id as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
    }
    return []
}
```

Steps to re-produce

1. Have two UICollectionViews with the above delegate methods implemented
2. Both should span across the screen
3. Drag an item from one and try holding on top of the other towards the edge of the screen pretending to drop it
4. Observe the items re-arranging making room for the new item (to be dropped item)
5. Slide your finger away from the screen and observe how the it appears as if the drag got cancelled.
6. Observe that the elements which got re-arranged making room for the new item still stays the same. If you have console logs for the layout delegate methods of the collection view you may observe they keep getting called
7. Now if you try to drag an item again or try to navigate away from the screen app crashes.

If any of you have any insight to what is happening, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending any interactive movement in the drop location (UICollectionView) when initiating a new drag fixed my problem. I had to modify my UICollectionViewDragDelegate method as follows,

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {

    var item: Item?
    if collectionView.tag == CollectionView.media.rawValue {
        item = mediaItems[indexPath.row]

// New line to fix the problem. 'timeline' is the IBOutlet of the UICollectionView I'm going to drop the item
        timeline.endInteractiveMovement()

    } else {
        item = StoryManager.sharedInstance.timelineItems[indexPath.row]

// New line to fix the problem. 'media' is the IBOutlet of the UICollectionView I'm going to drop the item
        media.endInteractiveMovement()

    }

    if let item = item {
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item.id as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
    }
    return []
}
```

To fix the app crashing upon navigation I had to end any interactive movement in viewWillDisappear.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

// 'media' and 'timeline' are the IBOutlets of the UICollectionViews I have implemented drag and drop
    timeline.endInteractiveMovement()
    media.endInteractiveMovement()
}
```

Hopefully, Apple will fix this in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much looks like `UICollectionViewDropDelegate`'s `dropSessionDidEnd` method is being called anytime one get's into this "issue". 
I think it's quite a bit more elegant to ensure to "end interactive movement" here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidEnd session: UIDropSession) {
    timeline.endInteractiveMovement()
    media.endInteractiveMovement()
}
```

Comment: i have used  endInteractiveMovement() but still i got crash, do you have any idea?

Comment: It's important, that you call it on both collection views (source and destination). Did you do that?